# Make group from list string

Tags: c#

I have one List as below:

```
var paths = new List<string> {                        

@"rootuploaded\samplefolder\1232_234234_1.jpg",
@"rootuploaded\samplefolder\1232_2342.jpg",                                      
@"rootuploaded\samplefolder\subfolder\1232_234234_1.jpg",                        
@"rootuploaded\samplefolder\subfolder\1232_2342.jpg",
@"rootuploaded\file-­5.txt",
@"rootuploaded\file­-67.txt",
@"rootuploaded\file­-a.txt",
@"rootuploaded\file1.txt",
@"rootuploaded\file5.txt",
@"rootuploaded\filea.txt",
@"rootuploaded\text.txt",
@"rootuploaded\file_sample_a.txt",
@"rootuploaded\file2.txt",
@"rootuploaded\file_sample.txt",
@"rootuploaded\samplefolder\1232_234234_2.bmp",
};
```

How to print output like this:

○ **Group 1**

```
rootuploaded\samplefolder\1232_234234_1.jpg,
rootuploaded\samplefolder\1232_234234_2.bmp
```

○ **Group 2**

```
rootuploaded\file1.txt
rootuploaded\file2.txt
rootuploaded\file5.txt
```

○ **Group 3**

```
rootuploaded\file-5.txt
rootuploaded\file-67.txt
```

○ **Group 4**

```
rootuploaded\file_sample.txt
rootuploaded\file_sample_a.txt
```

○ **Cannot grouped**

```
 rootuploaded\samplefolder\1232_2342.jpg
 rootuploaded\file-a.txt
 rootuploaded\filea.txt
 rootuploaded\text.txt
```

---

Grouping files based on 6 naming conventions (with top¬down priority):

1. FileName.ext, FileName_anything.ext, FileName_anythingelse.ext, ...
2. FileName.ext, FileName-anything.ext, FileName-anythingelse.ext, ...
3. FileName_1.ext, FileName_2.ext, ..., FileName_N.ext (maybe not continuous)
4. FileName-1.ext, FileName-2.ext, ..., FileName-N.ext (maybe not continuous)
5. FileName 1.ext, FileName 2.ext, ..., FileName N.ext (maybe not continuous)
6. FileName1.ext, FileName2.ext, ..., FileNameN.ext (maybe not continuous)

I used Linq to separate:

```
        var groups1 = paths.GroupBy(GetFileName, (key, g) => new
        {
            key = key,
            count = g.Count(),
            path = g.ToList()
        }).Where(x => x.count < 5 && x.count >= 2).ToList();

public string GetFileName(string fileName)
        {            
            var index = 0;

        if (fileName.Contains("_"))
            index = fileName.IndexOf("_", StringComparison.Ordinal);    

        else if (fileName.Contains("-"))
                index = fileName.IndexOf("-", StringComparison.Ordinal); 

        var result = fileName.Substring(0, index);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Create a method that returns 1-6 based on the input string. Make a new object based on the input and the calculated number. Use Linq to group by the calculated number.

Comment: @JeroenHeier: Can you explain more clearly? :)

Comment: Is path interesting for you, or only Filename?
What about:
@"rootuploaded\samplefolder\subfolder\1232_234234_1.jpg",                 
@"rootuploaded\samplefolder\subfolder\1232_2342.jpg",

Comment: @sac1: It's only sample data. And output can not group :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
var groups = new []
{
    new { regex = @"rootuploaded\\samplefolder\\1232_234234_\d\..{3}", grp = 1 },
    new { regex = @"rootuploaded\\file\d\.txt", grp = 2 },
    new { regex = @"rootuploaded\\file-\d+\.txt", grp = 3 },
    new { regex = @"rootuploaded\\file_sample.*\.txt", grp = 4 },
};

var results =
    from path in paths
    group path by
        groups
            .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(path, x.regex))
            .Select(x => x.grp)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(99)
            .First()
        into gpaths
    orderby gpaths.Key
    select new
    {
        Group = gpaths.Key,
        Files = gpaths.ToArray(),
    };
```

That gives you this:

[image: results]

You would just have to jig around with the regex until you get exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Voted :D

Comment: Sadly Its working only with these filenames. It's not a generic solution.

Comment: @sac1 - What do you mean?

Comment: If your filename is not '1232_234234_*' or 'file*' or 'file-' or 'file_sample*'
your code will not working. eg: for {rootuploaded\myfile-1.txt; rootuploaded\myfile-2.txt}

Comment: @sac1 - It's just a matter of changing the regex to suit the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, 1. and 2. group turn this solution difficult. Cause both contain 'FileName.ext', so it has to check whole list together :(

I try to separate groupping 1. 2. and 3 - 6:

### First step:

Find and remove Group 1 and 2 candidates.
It orders the list base on file path:

```
var orderedFilenames = pathsDistinct().OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
```

Than find Group 1 and 2 candidates:

```
var groupped = orderedFilenames.GroupBy(s => GetStarterFileName(s, orderedFilenames));

private static string GetStarterFileName(string fileNameMatcher, List<string> orderedFilenames)
{
    string fileNameMatcherWOExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNameMatcher);
    return orderedFilenames.FirstOrDefault(p =>
        {
            if (p == fileNameMatcher) return true;

            string p_directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(p);
            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNameMatcher);
            if (p_directory != directory) return false;

            string pure = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p);

            if (!fileNameMatcherWOExt.StartsWith(pure)) return false;

            if (fileNameMatcherWOExt.Length <= pure.Length) return false;

            char separator = fileNameMatcherWOExt[pure.Length];
            if (separator != '_' && separator != '-') return false;
            return true;
        });
}
```

### Step two:

After first step, you got Group 1 and 2 candidates, but all others are separated into different groups.

Collect remaining path and separete group 1 and 2:

```
var mergedGroupps = groupped.Where(grp => grp.Count() == 1).SelectMany(grp => grp);
var starterFileNameGroups = groupped.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1);
```

### Step three

Now you could find 3-6 based on regex validation:

```
var endWithNumbersGroups = mergedGroupps.GroupBy(s => GetEndWithNumber(s));
private static string GetEndWithNumber(string fileNameMatcher)
{
    string fileNameWithoutExtesion = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNameMatcher), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNameMatcher));

    string filename = null;

    filename = CheckWithRegex(@"_(\d+)$", fileNameWithoutExtesion, 1);
    if (filename != null) return filename;

    filename = CheckWithRegex(@"-(\d+)$", fileNameWithoutExtesion, 1);
    if (filename != null) return filename;

    filename = CheckWithRegex(@" (\d+)$", fileNameWithoutExtesion, 1);
    if (filename != null) return filename;

    filename = CheckWithRegex(@"(\d+)$", fileNameWithoutExtesion);
    if (filename != null) return filename;

    return fileNameWithoutExtesion;
}


private static string CheckWithRegex(string p, string filename, int additionalCharLength = 0)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(p, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
    Match match = regex.Match(filename);
    if (match.Success)
        return filename.Substring(0, filename.Length - (match.Groups[0].Length - additionalCharLength));
    return null;
}
```

### Final Step:

Collect non groupped items and merge Group 1-2 and 3-6 candidates

```
var nonGroupped = endWithNumbersGroups.Where(grp => grp.Count() == 1).SelectMany(grp => grp);
endWithNumbersGroups = endWithNumbersGroups.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1);

var result = starterFileNameGroups.Concat(endWithNumbersGroups);
```

You could try to solve both step in one shot, but as you see groupping mechanism are different. My solution is not so beautiful, but I think it's clear... maybe :)

Comment: Your solution is good. But I think it need to modify a little. If I have input data as below:
-  "rootuploaded\samplefolder\1232_234234_2.bmp",
-  "rootuploaded\1232_234234_3.bmp". 

It will be a group follow your solution, right? ^ ^

Comment: So you need directory separation as well?

Comment: Oh yep. The first I find all sub folder, and then get all files into each sub folder. And finally apply your solution. It's so good. Thank for your help ^ ^

Comment: Oh yep. Thanks a lot :D